# Open IOS Application which uses sharekit via fbconnect and/or sharekit from facebook app or facebook website

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, sharekit

Does anyone of you know if it is possible to open a App which uses sharekit from a Facebook request by clicking on the request either in the facebook app, or in the browser?
I could not find anything about this in the web.

To be more precise i want my app which uses sharekit to send a request to a facebook-friend. This facebook friend should then be able to open the same app by clicking on the request either in the facebook app on his mobile device or by clicking on the request on the facebook browser page which is opened on his mobile device.

I already know how to share things in facebook via sharekit, but to get it "the other way round" seems to be difficult. I could not find anything helpful in the web so far.

Greets and many thanks in advance,

Maverick1st

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your will will need to register itself as a protocol handler, and the link clicked on from Facebook app would need to use the url scheme you define.

Example:

my-social-app://invite/1234

Keep in mind if the recipient does not have the app installed, or they do this on their desktop machine, they will get a message that the phone is unable to open that URL.

See this tutorial: http://mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/